# failing to move uploaded video file

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am uploading a video via an online form. Here is the piece of code:

```
$path = "../user_uploads/user_media/" . $uid . "/";

$videoFile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
$imageFile = $uid . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
if (move_uploaded_file($videoFile, $path . $videoFile)) {
    $getFromSecond = 5;
    $size          = "350x200";
    $cmd           = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
    if (shell_exec($cmd)) {
        $picres = "y";
    } else {
        $picres = "";

    }
```

Can you tell me why it is failing to move_uploaded_file ?

Comment: try to dump `move_uploaded_file($videoFile, $path . $videoFile)`.

Comment: Check `$_FILES['files']['error']` for the value of 6. Sometimes no temporary directory is defined.